# How can I get "Number of dice in pool A higher than highest of pool B" in anydice?

Tags: statistics, anydice

What I'm looking for is this: pools A and B roll Xd6 and Yd6, respectively.
The result is determined as follows:

1. The highest roll among all dice is *r*<sub>h</sub>, and the pool it comes from is P<sub>h</sub>.
2. The other pool is P<sub>t</sub>, and the highest roll from that pool is *r*<sub>t</sub>.
3. The magnitude of the result, R, is equal to the number of rolls in P<sub>h</sub> that are higher than *r*<sub>t</sub>.
4. If P<sub>h</sub> is A, the result is +R. If P<sub>h</sub> is B, the result is -R. (If *r*<sub>h</sub> = *r*<sub>t</sub>, the result is a tie.)

Example:

```
[6 6 5] vs [1 2] -> winner is A, with R = +3
[4 4 3] vs [6 6] -> winner is B, with R = -2
[4 4] vs [4 4 2] -> tie, R = 0
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, that case you just removed would have been a tie, yes?

Answer (score 10):

*If* I'm reading your question correctly (which is not guaranteed: I've read through it a half-dozen times, and I'm still not 100% sure I've got it, but maybe that's what afternoon naps on snowy days do...), then the solution-function is almost the same as [Ilmari's answer from the linked post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178863/23970). The only change is what to do in case of a tie. (Nothing special!)

```
function: A:s vs B:s {
  result: (A > 1@B) - (B > 1@A)
}
```

Recall that a group of dice stored as a sequence (`A:s`) automatically sorts high-to-low and elements are @-accessed, so `1@A` outputs the first (*i.e.* highest) roll of group A. The comparison operator acting on a sequence vs. a number will generate a truth-count as its output, so `A>1@B` produces "the number of rolls in A greater than the highest of B". And in the case of a tie, we know (by construction) that `A>1@B` and `B>1@A` will *both* be zero, so we get the result you want =)

Function defined, if you want to see it in action a simple call like

```
output [6d6 vs 4d6] named "6 vs 4"
```

or

```
loop X over {3..6} {
  output [Xd6 vs 4d6] named "[X]d6 vs 4d6" 
}
```

will do the trick. It's pretty time-intensive, though, so you may end up running lots of "combats" individually.

---

*<sub>I will be donating all rep from this answer to a post of Ilmari's choice or, absent such a choice, to a post of Ilmari's that I choose (via bounty). Because this code is basically just theirs, with one tweak to fit your tie-condition.</sub>*

Comment: Oh, and here's [another opposed dice-pool question where Ilmari's basically already solved this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65447/23970).

Comment: Well, this is a first. I was thinking about answering this question, but apparently I already did. :D